# Boosting the realtime factor above 1

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible somehow to boost the realtime factor above 1??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6092/boosting-the-realtime-factor-above-1/) by [odedy86](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/297/odedy86/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 19 on 2014-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is a physics parameter called `real_time_update_rate`, which is the frequency at which physics time steps are advanced. The gazebo default is a time step of 0.001 ms and a `real_time_update_rate` of 1000, which multiplied together gives a real-time factor of 1. If you set the `real_time_update_rate` to 0, it will go as fast as it can. This can be done by modifying the world file (see [worlds/friction_demo.world](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/worlds/friction_demo.world#cl-25) for an example). It can also be done from the gzclient gui, by selecting Physics and then `real_time_update_rate`.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3